# Custom form in WordPress doesn't save in database after submission and show 404 error

Tags: php, wordpress

I have simple form

```
<form method="post" action="submit.php">
       <?php wp_nonce_field( 'my_nonce' ); ?>

     <label>First Name</label>
     <input type="text" placeholder="John" name="applicant-firstname" />

     <input type="submit" name="submit-button" id="submit-button" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

And in `submit.php`

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
    if (!empty($_POST) && isset( $_POST['submit-button'] )) {
       global $wpdb;
        $table = 'applicant';
        $data = array(
            'name' => $_POST['applicant-firstname']

        );
        $format = array(
            '%s'
        );
        $success=$wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format );
        if($success){
            wp_redirect( '/' ); 
            wp_die();
        }
    }
?>
```

The problem is that when I click on submit button I get url like `http://example/submit.php` which results in `404 error`.

Nothing is been saved in database also. Is that the proper way to submit custom form to database in WordPress?

Comment: is submit.php is available as accessible by wherever your form is? to check that, try adding /submit.php from the page that you have form. (ex: if you have form in mysite.com/formpage, then try mysite.com/formpage/submit.php)which will be 404. So what you can do is, move submit.php into root and the change this *<form method="post" action="submit.php">* into <form method="post" action="/submit.php">

Comment: Is that the only way? To be in the root directory?

Comment: And btw this return `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function insert() on null`

Comment: no, it's not the only way, however, your submit.php file should be accesible from the place where your form is

Comment: In this case what can be the reason to not be accessible?

Comment: did you try this? *if you have form in mysite.com/formpage, then try mysite.com/formpage/submit.php*

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how to try this. Do you mean as a action on the form?

Comment: no no, as a url. goto the page your form is. then add /submit.php to url to check if that php file is accessible

Comment: No, I get 404 error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192260/discussion-between-vishwa-and-jordan).